# Huawei Map and Location Kit - Bug when getMapAsync() is called inside LocationCallback

Tags: android, kotlin, maps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When I call getMapAsync() on onViewCreated() of the fragment, OnMapReady callback is triggering and displaying the maps on the screen.

But I need my getMapAsync call inside a LocationCallBack since I need my current location before displaying the maps.

The weird thing is onMapReady callback is not triggering when first entering the fragment with huawei maps when getMapAsync() is called inside the locationCallback. But when I navigate to an another fragment then popbackstack back to the fragment with huawei maps, onMapReady suddenly triggers and displays the map like there was no problem.

Does anyone experienced this bug? It always occur when first entering the fragment with huawei maps

This is how my location callback looks like:

```
  private var locationRequest: LocationRequest? = null
  private var locationCallback: LocationCallback? = null
  
  locationRequest
        ?: LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(30000)
            .setFastestInterval(10000)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(250.toFloat())
            .also {
                locationRequest = it }

  locationCallback
        ?: object :
            LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(
                locationResult: LocationResult?
            ) {
                locationResult
                    ?: return
                locationResult.lastLocation
                    ?: return

                currentLocation = LatLng(
                    locationResult.lastLocation.latitude, locationResult.lastLocation.longitude
                )

                // getMapAsync only if the map isn't initialized yet
                if (huaweiMap == null && this@SampleMapsFragment.isAdded) {

                    mSupportMapFragment?.getMapAsync(this@SampleMapsFragment)
                }

            }

            override fun onLocationAvailability(
                locationAvailability: LocationAvailability?
            ) {
            }
        }.also {
            locationCallback = it }

   locationClient
        ?: LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
            .also {
                locationClient = it }
```

Then I have this:

```
private var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

  locationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
```

Comment: Does `getMapAsync` really called? Maybe you have `locationResult`or `locationResult.lastLocation` `null` and do return before calling `getMapAsync`?

Comment: Yes I added a breakpoint and a log to be sure, and getMapAsync gets called when inside locationCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getMapAsync](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mapfragment-0000001050150294-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050150294__section11704105017376)() should be initialized when [the map is created](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-sdk-map-instance-creation-0000001062881706-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001062881706__section1148432115353). It is because initialization is not allowed during callback. If you want to obtain current location, and then display the map, you are advised to hide the map when you set it.

[image: map]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fixed the bug by doing what you said. I moved my getMapAsync call outside of the LocationCallback. Now I call getMapsAsync on onViewCreated() and put the call of LocationCallback inside onMapsReady callback. Basically I initialized the maps first and call locationcallback request after the maps was initialized. And I have a livedata that listens if I have both maps and current location, then I animate the maps to my current location